# problem with making preg_match for a username validating system

Tags: php, regex

I made this regex code:

```
/^([a-zA-Z\d]+[_]?+[a-zA-Z\d]){3,12}$/
```

I want the expression to:

- only allow it to start/end with any letter or digit
- allow a under score in the middle
- only 3 to 12 chars

When I test a name with more than 12 chars it still gives me a positive result.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Because you allow characters before the {3,12}. Why don't you just for `str_len()` after the regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{3,12}$)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:_[a-zA-Z\d]+)?$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,12}$)` - length allowed from 3 to 12 chars
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - 1+ letters or digits
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z\d]+)?` - an optional sequence of `_` and 1+ digits/digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Can you post a demo, please? I am trying to follow you to learn more about regex. You are a legend at explaining each pattern.

Comment: @YasserKhalil A demo of the regex? See [this regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/FlmFXw/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much.